# Fail to install Ubuntu 15.10 - Internal error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 as a dual-boot on my Windows 7 laptop, but I can't manage to. I am pretty sure the DVD is OK, since I used it to install it on my desktop (also dual-boot with Windows) last week without any problems. To be sure, I also ran the 'check disk' option today.

After telling the machine to boot from DVD, a logo is displayed with a loading bar. After that (i.e. before I choose to do a dual-boot or anything else), I get a message "Sorry, Ubuntu 15.10 has experienced an internal error". The details say it is ubiquity that crashed with 'dbus.exceptions.DBusException' and I can't read the rest of that line (how do you change the size of the crash report windows?)

From what I understand, ubiquity is the GUI installation program, so it is no wonder that clicking "Continue" doesn't bring me much further.
I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1495017) bug report that I guess is on this topic. Im a bit of a noob for Linux though, and the workarounds suggested are gibberish to me.

I tried to interrupt the boot from disk by pressing shift and then chose install Ubuntu (which didn't change anything) and also chose 'try Ubuntu' (instead of install), which immediately got me to a black screen with a few lines

> [ OK ] Started WPA supplicant
>
> [ OK ] Created slice ..
>
> [ OK ] Started Session ..
>
> [ OK ] Started User Manager ..
>
> [ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service

But after outputting these lines, nothing seemed to happen anymore. And the system wouldn't respond to any keys.

I find it strange that it did work on one system and not on another, using the same boot DVD. I really hope someone can figure it out and help me to get it installed. Thanks in advance!

Some specs of the sysem:

- HP Pavillion dv6 with Intel i7
- main drive: SSD
- Wifi adapter: Broadcom 4313 GN 802.11b/g/n 1x1
- Graphics adapter: Radeon HD 6770M (plus an Intel internal adapter)